# How to apply anti-alias effect in Photoshop just like the brush tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur, anti-aliasing

[image]

On the left side is a circle drawn by Brush Tool. On the right side is a circle drawn by Pencil Tool, with the same brush tip.

Is there a filter/tool to make the right one looks like the left one? I tried every single blur filter, but no matter how I adjust the parameter(s), it just looks much worse.

[image]

I've read [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4477/how-do-i-apply-anti-aliasing-to-the-edges-of-a-layer), but I need to automate this process as an action/script, so Pen Tool and Magic Lasso is not helping here. `Select and Mask` then `Global Refine` looks even worse.

I just want the anti-aliasing algorithm that Brush Tool uses. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there some reason you *must* use the Pencil tool rather than simply using a brush?

Comment: @Scott I'm processing images from someone else. I could manually paint the edge with brush tool, of course, but I'd like to know if it's possible to make an Photoshop action/script to do this in a batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an anti-aliasing filter that comes as standard in Photoshop.  Also blurring is not really the same thing as anti-aliasing so that's not really going to work anyway.

You could however use the Open Source G'MIC anti-aliasing filter in Photoshop. The download page is here: http://gmic.eu/download.html Note that I have no affiliation with the website or developers of this plugin. There are also versions of this plugin for GIMP, Krita, Affinity Photo, Corel PaintShop Pro, etc. And, I believe there's standalone and command line options too.

Example

[image]

There are also a couple of other anti-aliasing filters inside G'MIC (as you can see above). Try them to find the best one for your needs.  The Smooth (Antialias) works quite well too.

Here's an example of the Smooth (Antialias) filter, before and after side by side at 100%

[image]

As for applying to batches of images, you can record the filter in an Action, and apply the Action using *File > Automate > Batch*, although I think you will probably have to click OK on the filter each time it runs. I don't know how to suppress that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same thing. Anti-aliasing is is the process of removing/filtering the higher frequency signal from your image.

Now the image you have has no lower freqiency signal you have removed them completely. So there is no way of recovering them. Because they do not exist, atleast not at that size. So to properly antialias a image you need the higher frequency signals otherwise tge filtering is known as blurring. But blurring on its own wont bring tge same result.

So just resample the image to a smaller size then you have options for antialiasing.

Now this said you can build your own antialiasing into your image. Resample the image up with no AA (nearest neighbourhood filter) then paint in the missing data. Or after resampling apply a gaussian blur and then deconvolve the image with smart sharpen. Your blur must be more than one pixel and the deconvolve should be smaller than the blur. Then scale down this sometimes works. But is obviously not the same thing as actually having the extra data as everything gets a equally sharp fringe.